# Alternate harmonic series

Tags: summation, harmonic-numbers

Let $\alpha(n)= 1-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}-\ldots \ldots+(-1)^{n-1} \frac{1}{n}, n \in N$

If $\frac{p_{n}}{q_{n}}=\alpha(n)$

where $p_{n}, q_{n} \in N$ and $h c f\left(p_{n}, q_{n}\right)=1,$ then prove that $p_{n}$ is odd. Also prove or disprove that 1979 divides $p_{1319}$ : (where $a | n: a$ divides $n$ )

My solution:
I found manually , till n=6. The numerator is coming odd... but how do i prove it. Also in second part how to start?

Comment: This is (derived from) IMO 1979. What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: See https://prase.cz/kalva/imo/isoln/isoln791.html

Comment: I m stuck now at first part, proving Nr as odd and Dr even.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint 1:** Take common denominator. Track what happens to the $\frac{1}{2^k}$ term where $ 2^{k+1} > n \geq 2^k$

**Hint 2:** Rewrite the series. Observe that $ 1319 \approx \frac{2}{3} \times 1979$.
Also, 1979 is prime.

Comment: Yes second i got. First one i m not able to understand

Comment: @maveric Did you try what I wrote? If yes, show your work and explain where you got stuck / did not understand.

Comment: I dont understand when you said track the power of two?

Comment: @maveric When you make common denominator, what can you say about the numerator of the 1/2^k term? What can you say about the numerators of the other terms? Show what you've done.